# Download PDF generated from view

Tags: jquery, ajax, pdf, laravel, laravel-4

I'm already generating the pdf string with **thujohn/pdf-l4**.

What I want to do is download it when I click the download button with ajax.

I send the action post with the html data to

```
public function downloadPDF(){
    $data = Input::get('html');

    Return PDF::load($data, 'A4', 'portrait')->download('my_pdf');
}
```

and get response of

```
%PDF-1.3
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Outlines 2 0 R.......
```

what is the solution to automatically download the file?

Comment: Don't use `ajax` for downloading, just make a direct download link.